# Display Input Value Vertically CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an Input `type=number` in React, styled with `styled-components`. I need some of the inputs display it's value vertically

```
export const UnitValue = styled.input`
  ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  ::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
  }
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: ${props => {props.marginRight};
  margin-top: ${props => props.marginTop};
  margin-left: ${props => {props.marginLeft};
  width: ${props => {props.width};
  height: ${props => {props.height}
  border: ${props => {props.border};
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

Some inputs displays vertically but it's value is horizontal. I need that value to be displayed vertically, is there a way to do that? Here's the input:

[image: Input]

I need that the `input` value displays in the same direction of the text that is near to it without using `transform` css attribute. Is there a way?

Comment: What does the input looks like ? What does your CSS look like ? What does the desired result would look like ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Share image of expected out come.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your styles

```
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.